# ¿Cómo deben configurarse los puertos o URL del cliente y servidor en desarrollo?

Tags: url, servidor, backend, puertos, localhost

Tengo una aplicación que tiene dos servidores locales (localhost) para el frontend y backend respectivamente.

1. ¿Deben configurarse en el mismo puerto? Si la respuesta es si, ¿Cómo se hace? porque cuando lo hago el navegador renderiza solamente el backend.
2. ¿Deben configurarse en puertos distintos? Si la respuesta es si, ¿Cómo se hace? porque cuando lo hago la petición fetch me da el siguiente error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/tasks' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Yo creo que tienen que ir por puertos diferentes.
A cada servidor lo tienes que configurar para que escuche por puertos diferentes.
Digamos http://localhost:7070/ y http://localhost:8080/
Que software usas para cada uno de ellos?

Comment: Esta bien que corran en diferentes puertos lo que paso es que en tu aplicación del backend(sea cual sea el lenguaje pues no lo especificaste) debes habilitar el CORS para admitir peticiones desde otras fuentes. Dependiendo de tu lenguaje hay diferentes modos de activarlos.

Comment: backend: express y mongo
frontend: vuejs (quasar framework)

Comment: Entonces utiliza este paquete https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors para habilitar las peticiones

Comment: No entiendo muy bien como hacerlo. Ya lo he instalado, te muestro como he modificado el index.js de mi servidor en la pregunta que la he editado

Comment: descuida, me habia olvidado la linea const cors = require('cors');
de cualquier manera me resulta raro que para solucionarlo tenga que usar un recurso npm. Esperare a ver si encuentro/me dan una solución más "nativa". muchas gracias Jack!

Comment: En realidad el paquete no es necesario, solo necesitas modificar la cabecera para permitir el acceso y puedes escribir un middleware que lo realice. Te dejo la el ejemplo https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html